# Ops Hub Visual Studio Online - Refresh Online Users

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

Using OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility  v1.3.000b000 I am attempting to migrate a TFS2010 environment to Visual Studio Online.

When mapping the on premise users to the visual studio online users, I got the error:
Mapping of users with such duplicate display names is not supported by this utility.

I deleted users from the Visual Studio Online site so that there would only be one user per Display Name. However, when I open the migration tool, the duplicate entries persist. Is the online site user information cached either in Visual Studio Online or by the Migration Utility? Is there some way to force this data to refresh or is modifying the display names the only resolution?

Answer (score 0):

In case the in-tool refresh button does not get you the updated user list. You can try clearing the cache from

**%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache**

**%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache**

**%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache**

(Depending on the versions of VS/TFS you have installed)

Also ensure that the utility and all VS based application are closed before you clear the cache. After which the utility should load updated users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We modified the display names after all. I think an underlying issue with the accounts is the problem.